# Rasa NLU) Do I need to train whole intents again when I add new intents?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

Whenever I add new intents, Do I need to train whole intents and data again?

Or Is there any partial, continuous training instead of from scratch.

Because It takes too much time for training whole data, and get longer and longer.

I found some article and it said retraining all the time is good.

But it is 2 years ago.
[Retraining and updating an existing Rasa NLU model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343099/retraining-and-updating-an-existing-rasa-nlu-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, currently you need to retrain all the time

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26456435)

Comment: this is the answer to this question!

Comment: But this answer explains nothing. Next user comes with the same question, but he sees just your opinion. Use words "because" and make the answer more extensive. Otherwise this might have been just a comment.